# Google Invisible Recaptcha V2 Verify Form Fields

Tags: javascript

I am using Google Invisible Recaptcha V2. I want to check if form fields are filled/checked, like Name, Email, etc on the form submission. How to do that with javascript or jquery?

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>  

 <script>
      function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("Form1").submit();
      }
 </script>
 
<form method="POST"  action="Editform" name="Form1" id="Form1" />  

<input name="Name" id="name" required>
<input name="Email" id="email" type="email" required>
<input type="radio" value="S1" class="css-radio" id="radio1" name="AttA" />
<input type="radio" value="S2" class="css-radio" id="radio2" name="AttA" />
<input type="radio" value="S3" class="css-radio" id="radio3" name="AttA" />

<button class="g-recaptcha buttbox" data-sitekey="-------" data-callback="onSubmit" style="width:220px;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: What is the usecase of your <form>-tag? In my eyes, your html syntax is wrong.

Comment: And what exactly do you want to achive with the button element?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for those fields, like

```
document.querySelectorAll("form#Form1 [name]")
```

and you can search for the items whose value is falsy buy differing from 0:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("form#Form1 [name]")].filter(item => ((!item.value) && (item.value !== false)))
```

The ... is the reduce operator, used here to convert an array-like-object into an array, so we can call `filter` and pass an arrow `function` to it that will be executed for all items, the resulting array containing all `form` elements whose value is falsy but not 0. If the result's `length` is 0, then all elements were filled.